# Coffee similar in taste to Dallmayr Prodomo

Tags: flavor, bean-varieties

Someone brought back a pack of Dallmayr Prodomo beans from Poland about a year ago, and this is yet the best coffee I have tasted. I use aeropress for brewing. The Dallmayr was inexpensive in Poland, but costs a bit to import. So, can anyone suggest beans that taste similar to Dallmayr Prodomo?

Answer (score 1):

As Dallmayr is a german company you can try odering from their online shop, which promises to deliver to european countries.
Shop is found here: http://www.dallmayr-versand.de/epages/Dallmayr.sf/de_DE/?ObjectPath=/Shops/Dallmayr/Categories/KaffeeUndTee/Kaffee/Prodomo

Or you can try your luck with amazon and if it isn't available in your country's amazon, you can order it from the german amazon page: for a 12-pack https://www.amazon.de/Dallmayr-prodomo-gemahlen-500g-12er/dp/B000UGGVJI

Comment: This is not really answering the question. I know I can order from their page, and from amazon. However, it is a bit expensive to import. Do you know of some coffee that taste similar to the Dallmayr Prodomo?

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach it, would be to find out which kind of coffee beans this company uses, and then look for a small roaster, who has the same kind. Most likely, you will get a much better product from them. In order to find the small companies, you might like to check lists in the *Crema Coffee Guide 2023,* or check out options in your neighbourhood.